# Summing specific colums of multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have multiple dataframes as follows:

df1:

```
Month    Hrs
 Jan      5
 Feb      8 
 Mar     10
```

df2:

```
Month    Hrs
 Jan     10
 Feb      5
```

Required output:

```
Month    Hrs
 Jan     15
 Feb     13 
 Mar     10
```

My actual dataset and number of dataframes generated are large with some missing values also in it, while spanning throughout 12 months. How can I add specific columns, while keeping the months column as it is?

I have tried concat, joining and merge, with no result at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) with aggregate `sum`, `sort=False` is necessary for same order values of months:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2]).groupby('Month', sort=False, as_index=False).sum()
print (df)
  Month  Hrs
0   Jan   15
1   Feb   13
2   Mar   10
```

Comment: Ohh that was so easy, sorry for asking such silly question. I didn't try concat and groupby at the same time. Thank you for your help